# how to set character limit to MUI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, material-ui, autocomplete

hey guys i've created an auto complete with material ui and api
i want to set limit on it so whenever the user types 3 letters,the autocomplete return matched suggestions
can anyone please help?
heres my code bellow:

```
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';

export default function Demo() {
  const url = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players'
  const [jsonResult,setJsonResult] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json)=> setJsonResult(json.data));
  },[]);
  console.log('players',jsonResult);
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{width:300}}>
      <Autocomplete
        id="free-solo-demo"
        freeSolo
        getOptionLabel={(jsonResult)=> `${jsonResult.first_name} ${jsonResult.last_name}`}
        options={jsonResult}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option,value)=>
        option.first_name === value.first_name
        }
        noOptionsText={"No Match Found"}
        renderOption={(props,jsonResult)=>(
          <Box component="li" {...props} key={jsonResult.id}>
           {jsonResult.first_name} {jsonResult.last_name}
          </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params)=> 
       <TextField {...params} label="Player search"/>
      }
      /> 
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

i coulnd find any idea but any tutorial links is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a mask like this :

```
export default function FormattedInputs() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState<State>({
    textmask: '(100) 000-0000',
  });
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your input field:

```
          inputProps={{
            maxLength: 3
          }}
```